# RecyclerView with two adapter; ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, classcastexception

Currently I'm making a news reader app where it shows 
1 - Recent News
2 - Unread News

Basically I have two adapter for my recyclerview, one for recent news and another for unread news. For now the unread news adapter is just a copy for me to see how it'll behave and I'll do the sorting for unread news once I know for sure the adapter works. The recent adapter work just fine but when I click and run the unread adapter, it gives me this error :

```
11-09 06:16:11.766 2534-2534/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.azrie.dummyvoice, PID: 2534
                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.RecyclerView_Adapter_RecentNews$ViewHolder cannot be cast to com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.RecyclerView_Adapter_UnreadNews$ViewHolder
                                                 at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.RecyclerView_Adapter_UnreadNews.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView_Adapter_UnreadNews.java:18)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
```

This is my Recent News Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerView_Adapter_RecentNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_Adapter_RecentNews.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<Store_News_XML> newsXML;
Context context;

public RecyclerView_Adapter_RecentNews(Context context, ArrayList<Store_News_XML> newsXML){
    this.context = context;
    this.newsXML = newsXML;
    //this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    TextView text_title;
    TextView text_description;
    TextView text_date;
    View view;
    String currentLink;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        text_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_r);
        text_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_description_r);
        text_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text_r);


        view = itemView;

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card,parent,false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            newsXML.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setRead(true);

            /*for(int i = 0; i < newsXML.size(); i++){
                Log.d("News " + i + " ", " "+ newsXML.get(i).getRead() );
            }*/

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity_WebView.class);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("link", newsXML);
            bundle.putInt("position",holder.getLayoutPosition());

            intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Store_News_XML current = newsXML.get(position);

    holder.text_title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.text_description.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.text_date.setText(current.getPubDate());
    holder.currentLink = current.getLink();

   // Log .d("News Read Outside " + position ,"" + current.getRead() + " / News Title : " + current.getTitle());
    if(!newsXML.get(position).getRead()){
        //Log .d("News Not Read " + position ,"" + current.getRead() + " / News Title : " + current.getTitle());
        holder.text_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.text_description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.text_date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    else
    {
        //Log .d("News Read " + position ,"" + current.getRead() + " / News Title : " + current.getTitle());
        holder.text_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BAC1C1"));
        holder.text_description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BAC1C1"));
        holder.text_date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BAC1C1"));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsXML.size();
}



}
```

This is my Unread News Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerView_Adapter_UnreadNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_Adapter_UnreadNews.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<Store_News_XML> newsXML;
Context context;

public RecyclerView_Adapter_UnreadNews(Context context, ArrayList<Store_News_XML> newsXML){
    this.context = context;
    this.newsXML = newsXML;
    //this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    TextView text_title;
    TextView text_description;
    TextView text_date;
    View view;
    String currentLink;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        text_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_r);
        text_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_description_r);
        text_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text_r);


        view = itemView;

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card,parent,false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            newsXML.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setRead(true);

            /*for(int i = 0; i < newsXML.size(); i++){
                Log.d("News " + i + " ", " "+ newsXML.get(i).getRead() );
            }*/

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity_WebView.class);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("link", newsXML);
            bundle.putInt("position",holder.getLayoutPosition());

            intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Store_News_XML current = newsXML.get(position);

    holder.text_title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.text_description.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.text_date.setText(current.getPubDate());
    holder.currentLink = current.getLink();

   // Log .d("News Read Outside " + position ,"" + current.getRead() + " / News Title : " + current.getTitle());
    if(!newsXML.get(position).getRead()){
        //Log .d("News Not Read " + position ,"" + current.getRead() + " / News Title : " + current.getTitle());
        holder.text_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.text_description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.text_date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    else
    {
        //Log .d("News Read " + position ,"" + current.getRead() + " / News Title : " + current.getTitle());
        holder.text_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BAC1C1"));
        holder.text_description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BAC1C1"));
        holder.text_date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BAC1C1"));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsXML.size();
}



}
```

I'm sorry for the messy and unstructured code, I'm fairly new to programming. Thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: ok, make both `ViewHolder` inner class's private inside of public then try

Comment: Or  change `final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);` to final `RecyclerView_Adapter_RecentNews.ViewHolder holder = new RecyclerView_Adapter_RecentNews.ViewHolder(view);` same in other class

Comment: why are you using two different adapter classes if they both do the same job?

Comment: @pskink I was trying to test the behavior of the the recyclerview. Once it work as intended, I'm planning to change how the other class behave.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I tried both of your suggestion but it still gives the same error

Comment: I think you should use single recyclerview adapter, and pass your values in adapter. To test behaviour of recyclerview you can use see demo https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView

Comment: @MultidotsSolutions You're right. I should've done that in the first place instead of making things complicated.